# Limit Excel Macro Usage to Certain Users

Tags: microsoft-excel, security, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I want my Excel macros to activate for certain users recognized by Windows Excel. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the environ("username") to get the user's Window's Logon ID. You can use that to determine if the macro should run or not.

Comment: +1 I've never seen that before. I expanded on how it would work as an example answer below

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the [existing answer](https://superuser.com/a/949921/116196), you'll need something like this for each macro -

```
Sub macro1()
    If test() Then
        MsgBox ("you can use macros!")
    'do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

You will start all macros calling `test()`

```
Function test()
test = False
'Pass the user to the checking function
If allowed(Environ("username")) Then
    test = True
    Else: MsgBox ("You can't use macros here")
End If
End Function
```

This function will call your check to see if the user is part of the allowed list:

```
Public Function allowed(ByRef TF As String) As Boolean
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("name1", "name2", "name3")

    For Each Item In arr
        If Item = TF Then
        allowed = True
        Exit Function
        Else: allowed = False
        End If
    Next

End Function
```